# not a group by expression/not a single group funciton

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
select countryid, countryname, continents.continent, count(countryid) as carcount
from countries, continents
group by countryid;
```

The above is the code that I am having an issue with. earlier when I ran it without `continents` it worked fine but after adding `continents` I ended up with one of the following errors:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

How would I fix these errors?

I am trying to output the country id, country name, continent name and the number of cars produced by each country in descending order (I haven't gotten to ordering it yet so please let me try that on my own).

I am using Oracle's livesql if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `GROUP BY`, all columns that are not aggregated (wrapped in `SUM()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, `COUNT()`) must be in the `GROUP BY` column list. You're only using `countryid`, which is causing the error.

What you need instead is to include everything except `count(countryid)`.

```
select 
  countryid, countryname, continents.continent, count(countryid) as carcount
from 
  countries, continents
group by countryid, countryname, continents.contenent
```